# How can I replace only the first character of a string in MIPS?

Tags: string, assembly, char, byte, mips

I have written a MIPS assembly language code using `sw` instruction so that I can only replace the 1st character of a string with a character of my choice.

But, what happens is, the instead of **only** changing one character, the code changes the 1st character plus destroys characters in next three bytes.

How can I get it right?

I have written the following code:

```
# replace 1st character of a string
.data
string: .asciiz "ABCDEFGH"

.text
main:
# load string's 1st address into the memory
la $a0, string
li $t0, 'X'
#addi $t0,$t0, 48

sw $t0, ($a0)

# print string  
la $a0, string # load 1st address of the string
li $v0, 4 # syscall for string print   
syscall

# exit program
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Input: `ABCDEFGH`
Expected result: `XBCDEFGH`
Actual result: `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly use `sw` that stores a word, ie a 4-bte data.

In your algorithm, after the instruction

```
li $t0, 'X'
```

you write 'X' *as a 32 bits word* in your t0 register. Probably your machine is configured as [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and `$t0`, that is a 32 bits register holds the value 0x00000058 (0x58 is the ascii code of X).

When you write it to memory with `sw $t0, ($a0)`, all the 32 bits are written and the content of your memory, that was originally "ABCDEFGH" becomes "X\0\0\0EFGH".

When you ask to print it, the '\0' at position `string+1` is considered as an end-of-string terminator and you have just 'X' displayed.

The fix is just to replace the line with

```
sw $t0, ($a0)
```

with

```
sb $t0, ($a0)
```

and only the least significant byte of your register (ie 'X') is written to memory.